# no obtengo ningun dato de la web api

Tags: php, webapi

buen dia a todos

tengo una api que me trae unos datos, pero al momento de supuestamente consumir la webapi con php, no obtengo ningun dato, requiero de su ayuda que estoy haciendo mal

este es mi codigo pequeño de php

```
<?php
$usuario = file_get_contents('https://localhost:7105/usuarios/Consultar?idusuario=123456');
$cont = json_decode($usuario)
print_r($cont);
?>
```

y esta es mi webapi los datos que trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es lo que me sale en el source de consola
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de la webapi que envia los resultados

```
public static Usuarios Obtener(int idusuario)
        {
            Usuarios oUsuario = new Usuarios();
            using (SqlConnection oConexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("consultarusuario", oConexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUSer", idusuario);
                try
                {
                    oConexion.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            oUsuario = new Usuarios()
                            {
                                iduser = Convert.ToInt32(dr["iduser"]),
                                nombre = dr["nombre"].ToString(),
                                username = dr["username"].ToString(),
                                pass = dr["pass"].ToString(),
                                email = dr["email"].ToString(),
                                dob = dr["dob"].ToString(),
                                localidad = dr["localidad"].ToString(),
                                provincia = dr["provincia"].ToString(),
                                estado = Convert.ToInt32(dr["estado"]),
                            };
                        }

                    }
                    return oUsuario;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return oUsuario;
                }
            }
            
        }
```

gracias

Comment: que error te manda que te sale? ya hiciste el `json_decode($usuario)` ?

Comment: si, ya lo hice y no me sale nada, no me sale ni siquiera error

Comment: se requiere mas informacion acerca de este problema, podrias colocar el codigo de tu api, como haces la llamada y si este dato existe.

Comment: listo mira, ya actualice mas

Comment: coloca esto al inico de tu archivo php para que muestre todos los errores porque hay parese que no encuentra la url `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: ya lo coloque y nada, sale lo mismo

Comment: hasle un print a tu funcion `Usuarios Obtener` a ver que id resibe y que esta retornando...

Comment: Esto no esta devolviendo un error? crei decirte que no hicieras esas cosas en el try, estas encapsulando los erroes y no sabemos que pasa!!! estas ejecutando un noquery, y despues un reader.. tu SP que devuelve?

Comment: no devuelve ningun error, ya obtengo los datos, al colocar una url ya me trae los contenidos, no puedo es capturar el contenido que obtengo

Comment: ah ok.. igual tu codigo no esta bien.. estas ejecutando dos veces el SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nuevamente fallaste, ya me dieron la solución, para los que lleguen a tener este problema, deben agregar unas lineas en su web api, especificamente en el program.cs

asi quedaria el Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(name: "widthoutCors",
        builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors("widthoutCors");
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```